# Theme editing: bash: change color of heredoc

Tags: themes

I am editing a bash theme file for emacs. I can't seem to figure out which keyword defines the color of heredoc in bash.

(e.g.:

```
cat<<EOF
some code here
EOF
```

)

How can I set the color coding for these blocks?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your cursor within the heredoc, and do `M-x customize-face`: the face suggested by default should be the one present under the cursor.

Comment: I wish folks would pay more attention to usability. "tan1" on white isn't as bad as yellow on white, but still ....

Comment: @Bruce: we spend a fair bit of time fiddling with the default faces so they're legible.  So if they're not legible for you, I recommend you `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Okay. If you have access to Photoshop, you can put the foreground and background colors into an image and ask it to tell you about the contrast. (My Apple has died and won't have a replacement for two more weeks, so I can't. But it's a nice feature that would give you some confirmation about contrast and legibility. I'm also out of town using a laptop without emacs, so M-x report-emacs-bug isn't available for a couple of days, too. :)